# When can we use substitutions and why is this the case?

Tags: integration, substitution

I originally posted this as a second part to a messy slew of questions I had on some lecture notes I had, so I decided to take the suggestion of some users and post this question individually.

I have a question I find I can't properly explain. In any integration by trig substitution problem you have to state something along the lines of this, for example:

$x = sin\ u$

What is this insinuating? Why am I allowed to even do this without it changing the problem entirely in the same way that this substitution is invalid?:

- $x + 4 = 10$
- Let $x = sin\ y$
- Therefore $sin\ y = 6$

Why is the above not okay other than the obvious that $sin\ y = 6$ is impossible yet it's okay in integration by trig substitution? Is that because of our changing the differential variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where the substitution would require you to be able to say that sometimes $\sin y = 6,$ the substitution is *not* OK.

For example, you wouldn't make the substitution $x = \sin y$ in order to integrate
$\int x^2 \,dx,$ 
partly because you already know how to do that integral without the substitution, but also because $x = \sin y$ would give you an integral that is valid only for $-1\leq x \leq 1,$
whereas the original integral is valid for all $x.$

On the other hand, if you have to integrate
$$ \int \sqrt{1 - x^2} \,dx,$$
then the integral is *already* valid only for $-1\leq x \leq 1,$
because for $\lvert x\rvert > 1$ we would have $1 - x^2 < 0,$
and the square root of a negative number takes us outside the
domain of real-number integration.
So in that case you don't lose anything by substituting $x = \sin y.$

Comment: I see, so by making the $sin\ y$ substitution I'm implementing a domain restriction, since −1≤$sin\ y$≤1, and this would not accurately represent the integral at values other less than -1 or greater than 1. But since, like in your example, the function's domain already only lies there, such a substitution could accurately still represent the function? Hopefully this question makes sense. Like, essentially −1≤x≤1 and −1≤$sin\ y$≤1 so $sin\ y = x$?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. It works as you said.